# Compatible edition of RSA & WebSphere considering Java version

Tags: java, websphere, rational-rsa

One of my customer is using WebSphere Application Server ND 8.5.5.8 and Rational Software Architect 7.5 under AIX with java version 7.

The customer also using custom Java framework which is based on Java version 7.

Considering a EOS of WAS / RSA / Java , they willing to upgrade their environment to Java version 8.

If this is the case, Which RSA / WAS edition - version is compatible with java version 8 ?

In short, what is the minimum version of RSA / WAS to support Java version 8 ?

They want to have minimal version change for the RSA / WAS product considering EOS / Java Version change.

Comment: Did you try these programs with Java8 and verified that they do not work?

Comment: Not yet, they just planning to upgrade from Java7 to Java8 and need to find compatible WebSphere ND / RSA version with minimum changes.

Comment: You can install both Java7 and Java8 on the same AIX machine, so you can perform such tests.